# Javascript promise in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

will javascript promise work in VF page?. for me its not working while I am trying .then() function.Did anybody do anything like this?

This is my code

```
var pdf = null;
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
var pages = new Array();
    //Prepare some things
    var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var scale = 1.5;
    PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(_pdf) {
        pdf = _pdf;
        //Render all the pages on a single canvas
        for(var i = 1; i <= pdf.numPages; i ++){
            pdf.getPage(i).then(function getPage(page){
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
                canvas.width = viewport.width;
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});
                pages[i-1] = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                p.Out("pre-rendered page " + i);
            });
        }

    //Now we have all 'dem Pages in "pages" and need to render 'em out
    canvas.height = 0;
    var start = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++){
        if(canvas.width < pages[i].width) canvas.width = pages[i].width;
        canvas.height = canvas.height + pages[i].height;
        context.putImageData(pages[i], 0, start);
        start += pages[i].height;
    }
    });
```

then() function shows undefind error

Comment: VF just creates an HTML page, so there's no reason why it shouldn't work. Maybe you can share your code and describe your problem in greater detail.

Comment: ... such as the line that the error occurs on.

Comment: Hm... I've never given names to such functions. Have you tried to use anonymous functions? Like '.then(function(_pdf)...' instead of '.then(function getPdfHelloWorld(_pdf)...'

Comment: This is also not working formeFrankZ

Comment: Is there any problems for executing javascript async functions in VF pages?

Comment: No. Async functions work fine. They are not executed "in VF pages" anyway, but in your browser.

Comment: yes u are correct this code will work fine if u do it in an html page. But showing error in the VF page

Comment: I am unable to help you with the information given. Though I can say that VF does not prevent you from using asynchronous Javascript